# Mouse Zooming not Working for dc.js Line Chart

Tags: charts, zooming, render, dc.js

I'm creating an Angular wrapper for the [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) library. I've been closely following the [annotated source](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) to get some examples working, and I've had some success with pie and row charts. I was able to get the line chart working and I can select regions with the brush. I am not, however, able to zoom. I have disabled the brush and enabled mouse zooming.

When I hover the chart and move my scroll wheel the other charts on the page react, so filters *are* taking effect. When I select a slice of a pie it does filter down the chart:

[image]

[image]

In the documentation I noticed there's a `zoomed` event. I do not see any usage of `.on('zoomed', ...)` in the annotated source, yet the resultant [line chart](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) very clearly (and cleanly) supports zooming. I'm unsure if I need to implement a listener to redefine the domain zoomable chart's domain on zoom. If so, I'm not exactly sure how to get the lowest and greatest values for that new domain.

EDIT:
Gordon Woodhull has stated (in the comments) that the zoom functionality is derived from `d3-zoom`, so there is no need to listen to `zoomed` events and recalculate the domain.

Also a view into how the charts are being created in my wrapper. Charts components contain a `<div>` that it gives to dc.js to place a chart in. A Chart component takes as input a ChartSettings model to configure the chart before rendering it. A component that shows a chart would thus do the following:

```html
<dc-chart [settings]="priceChart"></dc-chart>
```

The Chart component itself uses the settings (which specifies the type) to determine the proper dc.js chart object to instance. The component then uses a service implementing crossfilter to retrieve the dimension and group for the desired domain and range (specified in the given settings). Using the settings and the service's response, the component configures the chart:

```js
let applicableMixins = {
  baseMixin: true, // The base mixin applies to all dc.js charts
  colorMixin: true, // The color mixin applies to all dc.js charts
  coordinateGridMixin: ["bar", "line", "bubble"].indexOf(cS.type) >= 0,
  marginMixin: ["row", "bar", "line", "bubble"].indexOf(cS.type) >= 0,
  // TODO: bubbleMixin
  // TODO: capMixin
  // TODO: stackMixin
}

let c = this.chart;
// Note: All chart settings are assigned default values in chart-settings.model, so there's no
// need to set default values here. All properties in a ChartSettings object are defined.
// Base Mixin
c.height( cS.height ); // fills parent when null
c.width( cS.width );
c.dimension(this.latestReceipt.dimension);
c.group(this.latestReceipt.group);

// Color Mixin
c.colors(d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10));

// Coordinate Grid Mixin
if(applicableMixins.coordinateGridMixin) {
  c.brushOn(false);
  c.elasticX(cS.elasticX);
  c.x(cS.xScale); // d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(1985, 1, 1), new Date(1986, 4, 1)])
  c.round(d3.timeMonth.round); // from example
  c.xUnits(d3.timeMonths); // from example
  c.renderArea(cS.renderArea); // true
  c.mouseZoomable(true);

  // Override for example.
  c.width(990);
  c.height(200);

  c.elasticY(cS.elasticY); // true
  c.renderHorizontalGridLines(true);
  c.renderVerticalGridLines(false);
  c.zoomScale([0, 100]);
  c.zoomOutRestrict(false);
  c.margins({
    top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 25, left: 40
  });
}
```

In an attempt to get zooming working I mimicked the annotated source as much as possible. I'm using generated data that simulates the value of a stock that's a little more verbose than the data used in the dc.js mainpage example.

```
[
    {
        "open": 110.47,
        "high": 115.16,
        "low": 104.79,
        "close": 117.0982,
        "date": "01/01/1985",
        "quarter": 1,
        "isGain": true,
        "dayOfWeek": "Tue"
    },
    {
        "open": "117.10",
        "high": 120.58,
        "low": 117.03,
        "close": 124.126,
        "date": "01/02/1985",
        "quarter": 1,
        "isGain": true,
        "dayOfWeek": "Wed"
    },
    {
        "open": "124.13",
        "high": 128.31,
        "low": 116.28,
        "close": 119.16479999999999,
        "date": "01/03/1985",
        "quarter": 1,
        "isGain": false,
        "dayOfWeek": "Thu"
    },
    ...
    {
        "date": "04/01/1986",
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: Prior work: Tom Neyland made an Angular wrapper called [angular-dc](https://github.com/TomNeyland/angular-dc) but it was only for Angular 1 IIRC. Still, there might be stuff you can learn from it.

Comment: Focus/range chart functionality is built in and it looks like it doesn't use the zoomed event because it ties in directly to d3-zoom events. I'm not entirely clear on your question - is there any code you can share?

Comment: @Gordon The incantation at the end of my post worked! Thanks for responding, Gordon. I did see angular-dc; my implementation is similar in that the wrapper component is general purpose and takes its configuration via bindings (in my case a single `ChartSettings` object). I hate to frame my question as "why it no work," but that's kind of where I'm at. The line chart responds to selections made in other charts flawlessly, it's just that scrolling has no _visual_effect in the chart itself; the data visualized in other charts _does_ change, though. It's like the line chart isn't redrawn on zoom.

Comment: Hard to say without looking at some code; as you say, the built-in demos work. Anything you can share?

Comment: @Gordon I added some code. Did my best to choose stuff that gave a clear picture. The component is supposed to be general purpose, so there's a lot of code that resolves what settings apply etc. etc.

Comment: I see. The code didn't help as much as I hoped. Guess I would need to see it running in order to help debug it. Certainly if I just add `mouseZoomable(true)` to [the line chart example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/line.html) it zooms. The [transitions are a bit weird](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/507) but it works. Hard for me to guess what would cause zoom-filtering to happen without zoom-drawing. If I put a breakpoint on redraw it says onZoom -> _chart.focus -> zoomHandler -> _chart.redraw so I guess you could see where that's failing.

Comment: @Gordon I'll definitely take a look into that! I was able to enable zooming in your linked example. Maybe `_chart.focus` isn't resolving to anything? I don't have any problem getting the chart to redraw when calling the chart's `redraw()` function from within the component. Another question: would any other property, such as `.xUnits`, `.x`, or `.elasticX` have any effect on the ability to zoom?

Comment: Hard to guess without looking at running code, but I am pretty sure `.focus()` is defined :) I also tried zooming on [the basic composite example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/composite.html) and it's not that, probably something in your angular binding?

Comment: You do need `elasticX` not to be set - that will definitely disable zooming.

Comment: @Gordon ...it was `elasticX`. Thank you, Gordon.

Comment: Phew! Glad we figured it out. It sort of makes sense that the features are incompatible, but it might be nice to do "elastic only once" in that case.

Comment: @Gordon If you post a short answer about `elasticX` I'll mark it as correct so you can get those sweet, sweet rep. points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some back and forth, we figured out that the problem is simply that `elasticX` is not compatible with `mouseZoomable`, since it permanently locks the x scale domain to the full range of values in the data.

In order to allow `mouseZoomable(true)` you need to make sure `elasticX` is false.

Of course, this also means you need to calculate the X scale domain yourself, which is mildly annoying. Maybe dc.js should only "elast" the X domain once (on render) if both options are set. That would be convenient and probably what is expected.